# Geometry Ratio in right triangle

Tags: geometry

> In ABC, $\angle ACB=90$. Point O is chosen inside ABC such that [AOB]=[BOC]=[COA]. If OA=23 and OB=11, find $OC^2$.

Using the areas, we can find OD:OE:OF, where D, E, F are the feet of the altitudes from O to BC, AC, and AB, respectively. I have no idea how to proceed

Comment: $[AOB]$ means the area of the triangle AOB?

Comment: Yes, [AOB] is the area of AOB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the triangles AOB and COB. Draw for them the altitudes to BO, say these altitudes are AX and CY (X,Y - feet). These altitudes should be equal (because the areas of AOB and COB are equal).

Let BO intersects AC at point M.

Then the triangles AXM and CYM become identical since AX and CY are equal.

This means AM=CM.

Analogically you can prove that the other intersection points are all midpoints of the respective sides of triangle ABC.

So this point O is special - it is the centroid of ABC. Can you go on from there?

Answer (score 0):

With $D$ and $E$ as stated, note that $OD=\frac{AC}3$, $OE=\frac{BC}3$, then $AE=\frac{2AC}3$, $BD=\frac{2BC}3$.

Applying Pythagorean theorem to triangles AEO and ODB gives $4AC^2+BC^2=9\times 23^2$ and $AC^2+4BC^2=9\times 11^2$

Adding these gives $5(AC^2+BC^2)=9\times 650$

Replacing $AC^2+BC^2$ with $AB^2$ and rearranging gives $\frac{AB^2}9=130$

Also note that $OC=\frac{AB}3$, therefore:
$$OC^2=\frac{AB^2}9=130$$